# rails_admin keeps loading assets in a loop in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, rails-admin

I have a rails 4 app deployed on heroku which displays the following error:

```
2014-06-30T21:41:49.904494+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles"
2014-06-30T21:41:49.909372+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles"
2014-06-30T21:41:49.909380+00:00 app[web.1]:   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "profiles"
2014-06-30T21:41:49.914865+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_multiselect.html.haml (11.8ms)
2014-06-30T21:41:49.914875+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_multiselect.html.haml (11.8ms)
2014-06-30T21:41:49.677490+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml (4.4ms)
2014-06-30T21:41:49.888037+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml (2.7ms)
2014-06-30T21:41:50.330339+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml (6.1ms)
2014-06-30T21:41:50.330358+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rails_admin-0.6.2/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_field.html.haml (6.1ms)
```

This happens with every asset file rails_admin needs leading to an infinite loop and:

```
2014-06-30T21:41:38.404015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=2540M(496.1%)
2014-06-30T21:41:38.404374+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

I've tried using multiple dynos and applying somo configurations in `application.rb`

```
# config/application.rb

config.assets.precompile += ['rails_admin/rails_admin.css', 'rails_admin/rails_admin.js']
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```